# How do rails project know about rake tasks from other repositories

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rake

We have a rake task called `db:sanity_check` which exists in a 'core' repo.

Other repositories that we have also show this rake task.
But they do not define the rake task.  It 'comes' from core'

How do these other repositories know about the rake tasks from the 'core' repository ?
Is it because they include that repository in their Gemfile ?

I have a new repository that I want to have the `db:sanity_check available` for but I don't know how to have the reference to the task which exists in the other repo.

This is NOT about creating the task itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a rails project and you set your 'core' repository as a gem in the Gemfile, then rake has access to the 'core' rake tasks.